# Equivalent for np.add.at in tensorflow

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, numpy-ufunc

How do I convert a np.add.at statement into tensorflow?

```
np.add.at(dW, self.x.ravel(), dout.reshape(-1, self.D))
```

**Edit**

self.dW.shape is (V, D), self.D.shape is (N, D) and self.x.size is N

Comment: Expand on your question.  Are you trying to understand what the `add.at` does?  Or trying get something in `tensorflow` that does the same thing and at the same speed?  `add.at` is use to speed up iterative problems where the standard buffer `add` produces the wrong result.

Comment: Search `SO` for '[numpy] add.at' to see how `add.at` has been used solve various `numpy` problems.

Comment: Do you know if there are duplicate indices in `self.x`?  That's when `at` makes a difference.

Comment: I do understand what the code does. I am looking for an tensorflow alternative.

Comment: If anybody, who is open to do it in pytorch, comes here looking for a solution, check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65584479/3337089

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `np.add.at`, you probably want to look at [tf.SparseTensor](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/api_docs/python/sparse_ops.html), which represents a tensor by a list of values and a list of indices (which is more suitable for sparse data, hence the name).

So for your example:

```
np.add.at(dW, self.x.ravel(), dout.reshape(-1, self.D))
```

that would be (assuming `dW`, `x` and `dout` are tensors):

```
tf.sparse_add(dW, tf.SparseTensor(x, tf.reshape(dout, [-1])))
```

This is assuming `x` is of shape `[n, nDims]` (i.e. `x` is a 'list' of n indices, each of dimension `nDims`), and `dout` has shape `[n]`.

Comment: Actually in the original numpy code, dout is of shape (N, D). self.x.reshape(-1) gives array of shape (N, ). While dW has shape (V, D).

Comment: What is the shape of self.x? (before reshape) Your edit mentions it is of size N, but in case it is of shape N, why do you do .ravel()?

Comment: Actually the shape of x is different but it's size is N.

Comment: You could do tf.reshape(x, [-1]) to get a shape [N] tensor then.

Comment: If this sparse tensor is modeled on the scipy csr sparse matrix, duplicate indices are summed.  That's the kind of behavior that the unbuffered `add.at` is supposed to produce.

Comment: Thank you! Sorry for the late response.

Comment: Tensorflow now has `tf.tensor_scatter_nd_add` - I recommend using this instead of `sparse_add`.  Anecdotally, it seems to be 10x faster.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of what `np.add.at` does:

```
In [324]: a=np.ones((10,))
In [325]: x=np.array([1,2,3,1,4,5])
In [326]: b=np.array([1,1,1,1,1,1])
In [327]: np.add.at(a,x,b)
In [328]: a
Out[328]: array([ 1.,  3.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.])
```

If instead I use `+=`

```
In [331]: a1=np.ones((10,))
In [332]: a1[x]+=b
In [333]: a1
Out[333]: array([ 1.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.])
```

note that `a1[1]` is 2, not 3.

If instead I use an iterative solution

```
In [334]: a2=np.ones((10,))
In [335]: for i,j in zip(x,b):
     ...:     a2[i]+=j
     ...:     
In [336]: a2
Out[336]: array([ 1.,  3.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.])
```

it matches.

If `x` does not have duplicates then `+=` works just fine. But with the duplicates, the `add.at` is required to match the iterative solution.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit Do not use this one, use `tf.tensor_scatter_nd_add` instead, as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73378503/851699).  I'll leave this here for posterity.**

---

Here's Lars's answer, updated to match current TensorFlow api (2.8.1), made to handle multi-dimensional case, and turned into a complete function:

```
def tf_add_at(
        values: tf.Tensor,  # A length-N vector of values
        indices: tf.Tensor,  # A shape (N, ) or (N, D) vector of indices (where D is dimension of redsult)
        result_shape: Optional[Tuple[int, ...]] = None  # Shape of result array (e.g. (D, ), or (D1, D2)).  If null, take smallest that fits ixs.
        ) -> tf.Tensor:  # Resulting tensor, which will have result_shape, contain data in vals.
    """ Add the values, grouping by indices, into a tensor with the given shape  """
    indices = tf.cast(tf.reshape(indices, (indices.shape[0], -1)), dtype=tf.int64)  # Make sure ixs hav shape (n_indices, n_dims) - this line handles the 1d case
    if result_shape is None:
        result_shape = tf.reduce_max(indices, axis=0) + 1
    return tf.sparse.reduce_sum(SparseTensor(
        indices=tf.concat([indices, tf.range(len(indices), dtype=tf.int64)[:, None]], axis=1),
        values=values,
        dense_shape=tf.concat([result_shape, [len(indices)]], axis=0)
    ), axis=-1)
```

Which passes test:

```
def test_tf_add_at():

    # 1d case
    vals = tf.constant([2, 5, 7, 2, 0, 8, 3, 5])
    ixs = tf.constant([0, 2, 2, 2, 0, 4, 4, 3])
    desired = tf.constant([2+0, 0, 5+7+2, 5, 8+3])
    result = tf_add_at(vals=vals, ixs=ixs)
    assert np.array_equal(result.numpy(), desired.numpy())

    # 2d case
    vals = tf.constant([2, 5, 7, 2, 0, 8, 3, 5])
    ixs = tf.constant([(0, 0), (0, 2), (0, 2), (0, 2), (0, 0), (1, 1), (1, 1), (1, 0)])
    result = tf_add_at(vals=vals, ixs=ixs)
    desired = tf.constant([[2+0, 0, 5+7+2], [5, 8+3, 0]])
    assert np.array_equal(result.numpy(), desired.numpy())
```

Comment: Actually I just discovered `tf.math.segment_sum` https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/math/segment_sum - which does this already, but only for the 1d case, and it expects indices to be sorted.

Answer (score 0):

Use `tf.tensor_scatter_nd_add`.

Example use in test:

```
def test_tf_scatter_add():
    # 1d case
    vals = tf.constant([2, 5, 7, 2, 0, 8, 3, 5])
    ixs = tf.constant([0, 2, 2, 2, 0, 4, 4, 3])
    desired = tf.constant([2 + 0, 0, 5 + 7 + 2, 5, 8 + 3])
    result = tf.tensor_scatter_nd_add(tensor=tf.zeros(5, dtype=vals.dtype), indices=tf.reshape(ixs, (-1, 1)), updates=vals)
    assert np.array_equal(result.numpy(), desired.numpy())

    # 2d case
    vals = tf.constant([2, 5, 7, 2, 0, 8, 3, 5])
    ixs = tf.constant([(0, 0), (0, 2), (0, 2), (0, 2), (0, 0), (1, 1), (1, 1), (1, 0)])
    result = tf.tensor_scatter_nd_add(tensor=tf.zeros((2, 3), dtype=vals.dtype), indices=ixs, updates=vals)
    desired = tf.constant([[2 + 0, 0, 5 + 7 + 2], [5, 8 + 3, 0]])
    assert np.array_equal(result.numpy(), desired.numpy())
```